# LOCALSTORAGE not working offline. Works fine on a live-server

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, file-io

I wrote a tiny vanilla js app which stores the high scores in local storage. Every time that score is surpassed the high score is updated in the local storage and the DOM.

It's pretty basic and it works fine when I'm using a live server.

But when I'm running it directly from a file server it says:

> "Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window': Access is denied for this document."

How can I change access specifiers of a browser?

P.S: I tried using both Chrome(74) and Firefox(66) and faced similar issues.

Any ideas on how to solve this?